# why oozie hive2 actions are failing?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, kerberos, oozie

We are migrating existing (production CDH 5.8 cluster) oozie + hive2 jobs to new CDH 5.8 cluster. Unfortunately the hive2 actions are failing with the below error after migration.

> Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:
>   jdbc:hive2://xxxxx.yyy.net:10000/default: Peer indicated failure:
>   DIGEST-MD5: IO error acquiring \ password (state=08S01,code=0)

Could someone help me to understand the reason for the below error message ?

Comment: hive.server2.use.SSL is disabled and our cluster is KERBEROS authenticated. Do you think the property still work ?

Comment: What is the value set for `hive.server2.thrift.sasl.qop`?

Comment: Parameter itself not present in config file.

Comment: Can you add it with the value of `auth-conf`?

Comment: Sure we will try and one more point that existing cluster load balancer was not enabled but new once does have Load balancer.

Comment: I do not think that would be a problem, Since the error specifies `DIGEST-MD5`, this is more of an encryption issue.

Comment: hive.server2.use.SSL=false and no property of hive.server2.thrift.sasl.qop works in existing cluster with hive2. The question is how does it works ??

Comment: Oh, and both are of same hive version. How many Hiveservers are running behing the load balancer? Then, are the delegation tokens renewed properly?

Comment: To add more to this issue , Trace from hive logs. 2017-02-13 17:01:35,921 ERROR org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport: [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-6092]: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: IO error acquiring password [Caused by org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: token expired or does not exist: HIVE_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=william, renewer=hive, realUser=hive\
/xxxx, issueDate=1487001682228, maxDate=1487606482228, sequenceNumber=2, masterKeyId=5]

Comment: @franklinsijo three hive servers are running behind load balancers and through beeline we can able to connect to hive2.

Comment: After disable Load Balancer it worked.But not sure what causing the issue.

Comment: I believe this is a bug with HiveServer2, the error also is not much descriptive. I thought there was some mismatch of encryption mechanism.

Comment: Thanks it helped lot

Answer (score 0):

The default Hive Kerberos delegation token store method can cause failures with Oozie HiveServer2 actions in certain environments. Cloudera suggests using org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.ZooKeeperTokenStore, or connecting to a single HiveServer2 instance behind the load balancer to avoid this connection failure.

When using multiple HiveServer2 instances front-ended by a load balancer, Oozie Hive2 actions can start a connection and get a delegation token on the first HiveServer2, and then because of load-balancing, get another connection to the next HiveServer2 when making the query. This causes the second connection to fail.

For HiveMetaStore HA, it is recommended to use DBTokenStore instead of ZookeeperTokenStore in order to better support a large number of requests to HiveMetaStore. For HiveServer2 HA, use ZookeeperTokenStore until DBTokenStore is getting stable in CDH with HIVE-12270.

CM > Hive > Configuration > HiveServer2 Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hive-site.xml and enter:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.cluster.delegation.token.store.class</name>     
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.ZooKeeperTokenStore</value>
</property>
```

CM > Hive > Configuration > Hive Metastore Server Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hive-site.xml and enter:

```
<property> 
  <name>hive.cluster.delegation.token.store.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.DBTokenStore</value>  </property>
```

(this is optional if you have set "Hive Metastore Delegation Token Store" to "org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.DBTokenStore")